# The .html?option="name" script glitch

Tags: javascript, html

So I have about 20 projects to show on my website and since I don't want to create 20 HTML files for each of them, I use this script to link people to the specific projects they click on. And so the link is like: `http://mywebsite.com/projects.html?option="project1"`

The problem I notice is that it usually displays the first project for about 1 second or longer before it shows the project I click on, I don't know what's the cause, I don't know if it's a glitch. Is there a way to fix it?

The script and my html:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    var url = window.location.href;
    option = url.match(/option=(.*)/)[1];
    showDiv(option);
});

function showDiv(option) {
    $('.boxes').hide();
    $('#' + option).show();
}
```

```html
<a href="projects.html?option=haivinh" class="permalink">
   <div class="desktop-3 mobile-half columns">
      <div class="item">
         <h3>Sleep infographic</h3>
         <span class="category">Motion graphics</span>
         <div class="imgwrapper">
            <div class="imgcon">
               <img src="images/thumb_item07.gif" />
            </div>
            <div id="view">view</div>
         </div>
      </div>
      <!-- // .item -->
   </div>
   <!-- // .desktop-3 -->
</a>
```

HMTL of the project page:

```html
<div class="container">
<div class="boxes" id="haivinh">
   <div class="sidebar full-width">
      <div class="desktop-6 tablet-12 columns">
         <!-- 
            .sidebar here is to used to apply the same CSS styles (padding, margin, font-size, and etc) applied to "left-sidebar" and "right-sidebar" templates
            -->
         <div class="box-info">
            <h4 class="border-top">
            Metro train ad</h3>
            <p>The poster was made to promote the upcoming metro train system opening in Ho Chi Minh city in 2017. The idea is that our daily lives would be so much easier and more enjoyable going to work or school with Metro. </p>
         </div>
         <!-- // .box-info -->
      </div>
      <!-- // .desktop-6 -->
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Read about **FOUC**.

Answer (score 1):

My guess would be that you default to showing project 1. You can tell this because your `showDiv()` function starts with a `.hide()`. As your function is not run until `document.ready`, you may see the initial setup for a short period before the function is run.

To fix this, make sure everything is hidden *before* running your js.